# Counting duplicates with multiple criteria (SUM IF FREQUENCY MATCH)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to get a count of crashes from an event log using the SUM IF FREQUENCY MATCH combination of formulas.  **Column A** has all the event IDs (but there are duplicates that i would like to ignore in the count). **Column E** has the road name where the crash occurred and I only want to count the crashes that occur on specific roads (I-96, I-196, M-6, US-131, US-31).  **Column J** has the event type, where I only want to count "crash" events.  The event type must be crash to count, but it can be any of the 5 roads listed (hence the and/or function). There are occasionally blanks in column E so I don't want those to screw up the Match function, but the other columns referenced do not have any blanks.  Currently this is my formula below, but I'm just getting a value of "0" as a result after CRTL/SHIFT/ENTER.  Any ideas on where I went wrong??

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF('Sheet1'!$E:$E<>"",IF(AND('Sheet1'!$J:$J="Crash",OR('Sheet1'!$E:$E="I-96",'Sheet1'!$E:$E="I-196",'Sheet1'!$E:$E="M-6",'Sheet1'!$E:$E="US-131",'Sheet1'!$E:$E="US-31")),MATCH('Sheet1'!$A:$A,'Sheet1'!$A:$A,0))),ROW('Sheet1'!$A:$A)-ROW('Sheet1'!$A$1)),1))
```

Comment: You've got a lot of description and the formula you've tried, which is good.  But this has a bit of complexity.  It makes perfect sense to you because it's your spreadsheet and you're looking at it.  To other people, there's a lot of ambiguity and it isn't intuitively obvious.  It is also hard for people to develop and test a solution without sample data, or to troubleshoot your formula.  It would really help if you could mock-up a table of sample data, or at least add a screenshot.  Include what you expect the result to be for the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pivot table is in order:

try pivoting (which lets you filter) the data on roads, then put the crash type in your columns which will then aggregate the counts and give you the table you're looking for.

If Id's are unique, then you should 'remove duplicates' first.

[image]

Comment: Better add some illustration to justify your solution will help OP and the Community too !!

Answer (score -1):

**I would like to suggest two different methods to solve the issue:**

**Method 1:**

[image]

- To get the unique list of Roads got Crash, 
  enter this Array (CSE) Formula in Cell `E64`, 
  finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($B$64:$B$75, MATCH(0, IF($G$63=$C$64:$C$75, COUNTIF($E$63:$E63, $B$64:$B$75), ""), 0)),"")}
  ```
- Formula in Cell `F64`, also fill it down.

  `=COUNTIFS($B$64:$B$75,E64,$C$64:$C$75,$G$63)`
- Formula in Cell `F70`,

  `=SUM(F64:F68)`.

---

**Method 2:**

- After get the unique list of Roads got Crash, 
  using above shown Array Formula, enter this one 
  in Cell `F71`.

  `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$64:$B$75,$E$64:$E$68,0))*($C$64:$C$75=$G$63))`

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Write your concern,, to down vote this one, help me & the community also!!